# Is there a way to do autocompletion in irb to prepend namespaces?

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, irb

Is there a way to do autocompletion in irb to prepend namespaces? For example, if I have a class `SomeModule::User`, is it possible to do something like `User[TAB]` which would expand into `SomeModule::User` similar to what https://github.com/cldwalker/bond does.

Comment: In your question, could you show us the code you have?

Comment: I don't think there is much to show. I have a class `SomeModule::User` and every time I use it in irb I need to type the full name with the module. I'm trying to see if there is a way to add auto completion that would allow me to only type `User` and when pressing tab (or anything else) would present options of all classes/modules/etc that would match `User`